# Android: passing data between two different applications

Tags: android

My app I've got a chathead which appear on top of screen when specific app (chat program), are in foreground. 
When you are chatting with someone you can tap on it: a dialog window appear.
You can choose an image (simple png), and I want that image goes to opened chat (not chat list but chat dialog opened if it is. If it's not open, nothing append).
Now everything works but not image passage between my app and opened chat. 
with this:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager(); 

sendIconInt = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage();
```

I just get application chat list and not the opened one.
I think about RunningTaskInfo for now I've no success results.
Please let me now if you need further details and code.
I hope you'll can help me
thanks in advance
anne

Comment: use content provider to share data between apps. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Ok I'm trying. But how recover last chat window? Last program launched before touching my dialog from chathead?